# How to prevent AVAudioPlayer from playing before a view is displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, avaudioplayer

Hi there I have an a UIView named HomeViewController that use UINavigationController.  On a click of a button, I push another view using the following code:

```
gameView = [[GameViewControler alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:gameView animated:YES];
    [gameView release];
```

In GameViewController's viewDidLoad,  I use the following code to play two audio file one after another:

//handle sound stuff

```
if([[GameStore defaultStore] currentIndex] == 0)
{
    if(![audioPlayer isPlaying])
    {
        NSString *findPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"findtheword" ofType:@"aiff"];
        if(findPath)
        {
            NSURL *findURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:findPath];
            NSError *findError;
            audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:findURL error:&findError];

            if(audioPlayer == nil)
            {
                NSLog([findError description]);
            }
            else{
                [audioPlayer play];
            }
        }
    }
}

while ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
    //do nothing and wait so the sound is not overlap
}


if(![audioPlayer isPlaying] || ([audioPlayer isPlaying] && override)){
    Word *currentWord = [[GameStore defaultStore] currentWord];
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[currentWord fileName]
                                                      ofType:[currentWord fileType]];
    // If this file is actually in the bundle...
    if (soundPath) {
        // Create a file URL with this path
        NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog([error description]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
    }
    [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"GameViewController - playSound"];
}
else{
    [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"GameViewController - playSound is still playing"];
}
```

I can't figure out why the first audio file started to play while the screen is still on HomeViewController even though it is being called from GameViewController's viewDidLoad.

If I remove the following code:

```
while ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
    //do nothing and wait so the sound is not overlap
}
```

The first audio file started to play when GameViewController is loaded but the 2nd audio file overlap.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the audio file start to play after you click some button or table view cell in `HomeViewController`? As in, it starts to play while the `GameViewController`'s view is being animated from right to left? If so, then that's because `-viewDidLoad` is called before the view is actually presented. What you need to do is instead place your view logic in `-viewDidAppear:`. That will only be called when the view is finished animating and is completely visible.

Comment: what described is exactly what was happening.  I moved the code to -viewDidAppear and that seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: The correct method signature is `-viewDidAppear:`. `animated` is (typically) the name of the method argument.